# Multi Tcp server can only handle one connection

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, server, connection

i'm working on a tcp server that can handle many clients. Its written in c# async and callbacks.
So i'm finished but the server can only handle one connection... Somewehre contains an error but after 3 days of search i don't know where. i will paste the code. Funny: The client doesn't throw any errors. The server shows only one connected client. And other clients can't connect.

```
public class StateObject
{
    public Socket WorkSocket;
    public const int BufferSize = 32;
    public byte[] Buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
    public StringBuilder Sb = new StringBuilder();
}

internal class TcpServer
{
    public static Socket ServerSocket;
    public static List<SimClient> LbConnections = new List<SimClient>();

    public static async void StartTcpServerAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                ServerSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
                LbConnections = new List<SimClient>();
                var serverIp = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(Settings.Default.IPAddress), Settings.Default.Port);

                ServerSocket.Bind(serverIp);
                ServerSocket.Listen(0);
                InitServer.IsServerReady = true;

                ServerSocket.BeginAccept(AcceptCallback, ServerSocket);
            });
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            AdvancedLogging.WriteLog(e.Message + "(" + e.InnerException + ")", 2);
            InitServer.IsServerReady = false;
        }
    }

    private static void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        var listener = (Socket)result.AsyncState;
        var handler = listener.EndAccept(result);

        var state = new StateObject();
        state.WorkSocket = handler;

        LbConnections.Add(new SimClient { State = state });
        handler.BeginReceive(state.Buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, SocketFlags.None, ReceiveCallback, state);
    }

    private static void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        var state = (StateObject)result.AsyncState;
        var socket = state.WorkSocket;
        var received = socket.EndReceive(result);

        if (received <= 0)
        {
            socket.BeginReceive(state.Buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, SocketFlags.None, ReceiveCallback, state);
            return;
        }

        state.Sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(
            state.Buffer, 0, received));

        var content = state.Sb.ToString();
        if (content.IndexOf("<EOF>", StringComparison.Ordinal) > -1)
        {
            DataHandler.HandleData(content.Substring(0, content.Length - 5), state);
            state.Sb.Clear();
            socket.BeginReceive(state.Buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, SocketFlags.None, ReceiveCallback, state);
        }
        else
        {
            socket.BeginReceive(state.Buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, SocketFlags.None, ReceiveCallback, state);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the `BeginAccept` after you called `handler.BeginReceive`

```
private static void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult result)
{
    var listener = (Socket)result.AsyncState;
    var handler = listener.EndAccept(result);

    var state = new StateObject();
    state.WorkSocket = handler;

    LbConnections.Add(new SimClient { State = state });
    handler.BeginReceive(state.Buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, SocketFlags.None, ReceiveCallback, state);
    ServerSocket.BeginAccept(AcceptCallback, ServerSocket);  // <<---
}
```

It works the same as the `BeginReceive` and `EndReceive`.

---

In this case the `await Task.Run(() =>` is useless. You're mixing up two different methods.  TPL and Async callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

Mhh if i move ServerSocket.BeginAccept(AcceptCallback, ServerSocket); in AcceptCallback, AcceptCallback wouldn't be called any times.

EDIT
I foud the misstake. I need to call ServerSocket.BeginAccept(AcceptCallback, listener);
Thanks :)